# Ubuntu Touch - emacs gets 'fatally' stopped in terminal if user switches away to other touch applications

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

Here is my problem: I start 'emacs' in latest Ubuntu Touch running on Nexus 7. Then I swipe to switch to Unity desktop and there I launch, say, browser. Then I swipe again and switch back to terminal where I now see "Stopped" word in the middle right across the now frozen emacs text interface. Now the process is listed as stopped by `jobs` command and I try `fg %1` to bring it back to foreground. Unfortunately what I get is just some codes now start appearing across the screen every time I press any button from the moment I launched the `fg %1` command. Sometimes I get parts of emacs interface appearing on the screen but this is it. I am unable to recover my application back into the working state.

So here goes the questions:

1. Are there better ways to recover applications stopped in terminal by the system?
2. Are there ways to prevent application from being stopped by the system? Like some command line parameter to make app ignore SIGSTOP?

Answer (score 1):

With kind help from colleague the following looks like solution so far: start emacs not with default `emacs` but rather with `exec emacs`. So far this has withstood all the scenarios which caused 'stopped' problem before.

Comment: The only side effect found so far is what when user exits emacs which was lauched with `exec emacs` - there is no shell prompt anymore and this terminal tab seems to become useless and only could be closed. FYI.